# How do I convert Relative Humidity into specific humidity

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling

I am using NCEP_DOE reanalysis 2 data set. It include only relative humidity while I need specific humidity. How do I convert the relative humidity into specific humidity?

Comment: there is a nice answer to this here: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/5076/174

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-relative-humidity-air-d_688.html) gives the following equation for converting relative humidity to specific humidity.

> If we know the relative humidity of the moist air and the water vapor density and density of the air, the specific humidity can be expressed as:

```
x = 0.622 φ ρws / (ρ - ρws) 100%         (1)

where

x = specific humidity of air vapor mixture (kg/kg)

φ = relative humidity (%)

ρws = density of water vapor (kg/m3)

ρ = density of the moist or humid air (kg/m3)
```